# Loading a BIM360 model from a deployed site returns 9: BAD_DATA_NO_VIEWABLE_CONTENT

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have some JavaScript that calls the function `Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(...)`. When I run this locally, I am able to successfully load a model, but when the code is deployed the exact same model returns the error

```
9: BAD_DATA_NO_VIEWABLE_CONTENT
```

Any ideas what the issue would be?

Answer (score 0):

There are various reasons why loading a model from Forge could return the error code 9, for example:

- you are loading a model that has not been processed using the [POST job](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST) endpoint yet
- the model has already been processed but the translation failed for some reason (use the [GET :urn/manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET) endpoint to check if you see `"status": "success"`)
- the model was translated successfully but there is no actual viewable content in it (e.g. a Revit model with no 2D sheets and no 3D views specified)
- the model was translated successfully, but the output derivatives have been removed, either manually (using the [DELETE :urn/manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-DELETE) endpoint) or perhaps automatically after the original file was removed from a Forge OSS bucket

Comment: If you need more help, contact us directly via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`. If possible, include your Forge credentials (we won't share them with anyone outside of the company) and the URN of the model that's causing issues.